# Change embedded signature responsibility

Tags: docusignapi

I am embedding the signature request with DocuSign in my application. Is there any way that I can allow customers to change embedded signature responsibility(forward the document to someone else)?

I have already checked the setting to enable recipients to Assign to Someone Else according to this link: https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=yca1573855023892&topicId=uin1573855010064.html&_LANG=enus
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIT8f.png)

Another question, if it is impossible then is there any way that customers can save all the changes that they have made so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedded Signing doesn't directly support signers changing signing responsibility. This is because out-of-the-box if a captive signer did so, the recipient they changed it to would not have a way to access the envelope.

The most straightforward way to resolve this would be to change the signer to a Remote signer so that the Signer Reassign function you've linked would work.

If it's necessary for a signer to remain embedded/captive, but still have the ability to reassign, you would need to build out functionality in your application that would (outside of DocuSign)

- prompt the recipient for the new signer's info
- make an UpdateRecipient call on the envelope to change the name/email/clientUserId as needed
- Notify the new recipient that they have an envelope to sign
- Grant the new recipient access to the envelope.